# C# - Add contact in Office 365 - Forbidden error 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, office365

I want to add a new contact in Office 365 to use with outlook mail using C#. I have created below code to add contact in Office 365

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts"));

// Add the Authorization header with the basic login credentials.                
var auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("XXXXXXXX" + ":" + "XXXXXXXX"));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
request.Headers.Add("contact_folder_id", "test");

private const string odata = "@odata.type";
private const string type = "#Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Contact";

var createResponse = new JObject();
createResponse[odata] = type; // this needs to be here for this to work
createResponse["DisplayName"] = "Display Name";
createResponse["GivenName"] = "Given Name";
createResponse["MiddleName"] = "Middle Name";
createResponse["Surname"] = "Surname";
createResponse["EmailAddress1"] = "abc111@gmail.com";

request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createResponse));
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Above code is not working for me. I am getting 403 forbidden error in response and I am not able to create contact in office 365.

Comment: I added auth and updated question. But still I am getting same response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Office 365 accepts http basic authentication, it would explain why you are getting 403 forbidden as a response.

Try authenticating via OAuth instead.